# Xcode pin constraints not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I am brand new to iOS development (I have done some Android and Windows 8/ 10 development), and I am having the hardest time understanding constraints. I have read several online tutorials and am still confused. Currently, I dragged a label into the Storyboard designer and once I positioned  it, went to **Editor->Pin->Leading Space to Superview** and **Editor->Pin->Top Space to Superview**.

[image: Storyboard]

I *think* that that should work, but it doesn't. Event with the constraints the iPhone 6 simulator displays improperly.

[image: iPhone simulator]

I can't seem to figure this out. Why do my constraints not work?

I am using `wAny hAny`  and even added all pin constraints (top, bottom, leading, trailing).

Comment: are you desiging the layout on wAny hAny ?

Comment: you also need to give tralining space constraint to the label.

Comment: @T_77 sorry yeah I am. And at one point I added all pin constraints, (top, bottom, leading, trailing) it did not work, however.

Comment: @T_77 No you do not. UILabel is autosizing. If you do not give a trailing space to it, it will auto size to what ever text is inside the label.

Comment: @James_Parsons, what constant does your leading space constraint have? If maybe larger than the iPhone screen. Try setting a center horizontal constraint instead of the leading one.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your Label is too far to the right to be displayed.  (You could check its frame in your view controller's -viewDidLayoutSubviews method.)

But in order to make sure that you're writing code that centers the label for all iPhone resolutions, though, you want to use Align > Horizontal Center in Container.

Answer (score 1):

you must have given the constraint value too far. I tried your way , and yes it didnt showed for me too. I better understanding , I am attaching the screenshots too..

[image]

as you can see , the value I gave is more than 270 , and this constrtaint is fixed. This is too far from the screen.

Now lets try to give low value to the constraint:

[image]

Comment: it doesnt matter the width of the label. you can give any width to your label

Comment: you don't need a trailing space constraint

Comment: yes,i just tried to replicate what the author did and tried to show where did it go wrong for him.